# C# Specific value passing between forms without new instance

Tags: c#, listbox, picturebox

I have a C# application that allows the user to log certain events that occur in a game. For simplicity I'll call them `ParentForm` and `ChildForm`.

`ParentForm` is used 99% of the time, to log common events. This is represented as the user clicking a `PictureBox` and the `Tag` property of that `PictureBox` being added to a `ListBox`. When a "rare" event occurs, the user can click a "log rare event" button on `ParentForm` to open `ChildForm` which opens a set of "rare event" `PictureBoxes`, which function the same as in the `ParentForm`. The challenge is that I want these common and rare events to be logged to the same `ListBox`, so I am trying to find out how I would get a `PictureBox` click (and subsequent `Tag` from this `PictureBox`) on the `ChildForm` to the `ListBox` on the ParentForm.

The `ParentForm` does **not** close while `ChildForm` is open, and needs to stay open.

In the `ParentForm` code, I already have the code needed to capture one of the `PictureBox` clicks and grabbing the `Tag`, as well as handling dealing with adding it to the `ListBox`, so it'd be nice if I could just use these.

Here's what I've tried so far for the Parent:

```
// This file is EventLogger.cs
using rareEvent;
namespace mainWindow {
    public partial class EventLogger : Form {
        // In the ParentForm (listeners for PictureBox clicks are handled elsewhere)
        public void pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            PictureBox pbSender = (PictureBox) sender;

            // Open new window and handle "rare" drops
            if (pbSender.Tag.ToString() == "rare") {

                // Open rare form
                EventLogger.RareForm rare = new EventLogger.RareForm();
                rare.Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the child:

```
// This file is Rare.cs
using EventLogger;
namespace rareEvent {
    public partial class rareEventForm : Form {

        // In the ChildForm
        private void pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            // Does not compile if form is not instantiated, but I do not
            // want a new instance
            EventLogger form;
            form.pictureBox_Click(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

I figured something like this would work, but it gives the error

```
The type or namespace name 'EventLogger' does not exist in the namespace
'mainWindow' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. All the other examples I've found of value passing between forms all seem to create new instances which I don't want or were 8 years old and didn't work.

Appreciate it!

**Edit:** Code updated to have `using <namespace>` in each file. The problem still exists of not being able to send values between both forms **without** using `new`. (See comment to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38937492/3784049) answer)

Comment: You must pass arguments between two forms using instances, but you do not need to close the instances.  See two form project on following posting.  Lots have people have been using this code that I developed over 5 years ago.  Other experts have also recommended my code : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx.  I will be glad to answer any additional questions.

Comment: Not sure if you linked the right thing - that link goes to sockets and there is nothing said about 'two form project'

Comment: Your correct.  The link was a response for a different posting on TCP.  Here is correct link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first form create an instance (of it) here like my form1. It must be static and all datatypes you want to access should be public.

```
//FORM1
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Instance of this form
    public static Form1 instance;

    //For testing
    public string myProperty = "TEST";

    //Assign instance to this either in the constructor on on load like this 
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        instance = this;
    }
    //or
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Assign the instance to this class
        instance = this;
    }
```

Then in form2 when calling    EventLogger.RareForm rare = new EventLogger.RareForm(); instead of new form do

```
EventLogger.RareForm rare = EventLogger.RareForm.instance
```

Or in my case

```
Form1 frm = Form1.instance;
```

I then check the property of form 1 FROM form2 like so

```
Console.WriteLine(frm.myProperty);
```

Output was "Test"

Any trouble shout.

Comment: Perfect. The `instance` bit was everything I needed. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Pleasure to answer my first question

Comment: Awesome that's great :)